# Finding a range of values two other columns from based on values in another column

Tags: python

I'm trying trying to use python to find value ranges in two columns (TableA) based on values from the first column of TableB. Column 1 and Column 2 in TableA represent ranges of values Whenever, a value from column 1 in TableB falls within a range, I want to extract such rows from TableA as shown in the output and also know how many they are.

TableA:

```
1   524
677 822
902 1103
1239    1790
2001    2321
3900    4567
```

TableB:

```
351 aux
1256    sle
4002    aim
```

Required output:

```
1   524
1239    1790
3900    4567

Total count = 3
```

Here's my attempt that didn't work:

```
datA = open('TableA.txt','r')
datB = open('TableB.txt','r')

count=0
for line1 in datB:
    line1 = line1.strip().split()
    for line2 in datA:
    line2 = line2.strip().split('\t')
        for col1, col2 in zip(line2[0], line2[1]):
            if line2 > col1 and line2 < col2:
                print(col1 + '\t' + col2) 
                count=+1
print(count)
datA.close()
```

datB.close()

Can someone please help? Thanks

Comment: Your indentation of the `line2 = ...` line is wrong.

Comment: You don't need the `for col1, col2` loop.  Just `col1 = line2[0]` and `col2 = line2[1]`

Comment: You need to go back to the beginning of `datA` every time through the `line1` loop.

Comment: you're comparing values alpha-wise. You have to convert your values to integers.

Comment: If the values in table A are always sorted in ascending order and if you can store the whole table A in memory, you could use the bisect module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it this way:

```
tableBcol1=[int(i.split()[0]) for i in open('TableB.txt')]
tableA=[i.strip() for i in open('TableA.txt')]

count=0
for bcol1 in tableBcol1:
    for line in tableA:
        lbound,hbound=line.split()
        if bcol1 in range(int(lbound),int(hbound)+1):
            print(line.strip())
            count+=1

print(count)
```

`tableBcol1` contains all the values of column1 from `TableB.txt` in integer form (ie 351,1256,4002).

`lbound` and `hbound` contain the values from column1 and column2 from `TableA.txt`.

Finally, you check for membership in the `if` statement. If the value from column1 of `TableB.txt` is in the range then print the line from `TableA.txt`. Note, one is added to `hbound` in the range because the upper bound is non-inclusive.

Comment: Thanks so much for your code and explanations. Great solution. Problem solved!

Comment: With this code, TableA.txt will be opened once for every value in table B. It can be modified so that the file is opened only once, either by loading the whole file in a list or by using the `file.seek()` method.

Comment: @Gribouillis definitely a good point. I've updated to prevent that

Comment: Also if tables are large, this algorithm is O(|B| |A|), but if A is sorted, as it seems, there is an algorithm in O(|B| log2(|A|)) by performing binary search in array A.

Answer (score 1):

```
TableA = """1   524
            677 822
            902 1103
            1239    1790
            2001    2321
            3900    4567"""

TableB = """351 aux
            1256    sle
            4002    aim"""

#TableA = open('TableA.txt', 'r').read()
#TableB = open('TableB.txt', 'r').read()

ranksA = [map(int, e.split()) for e in TableA.split("\n")]
valuesB = [int(e.split()[0]) for e in TableB.split("\n")]

resultsraw = [(v, [(ri, rf) for ri, rf in ranksA if v >= ri and v <= rf]) for v in valuesB]
results = "\n".join(["%6s\t%6s" % e[1][0] for e in resultsraw])

print results
print "Total count: %s" % (len(resultsraw))
```

output:

```
     1     524
  1239    1790
  3900    4567
Total count: 3
```

Comment: I really appreciate your solution. Thanks JCA!

Answer (score 1):

Report and total the range for every item in Table B that falls within a range in Table A.

Here is another approach using `defaultdict` as a counter, `csv` for reading tabular data and `with` statements for safely opening/closing files:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

# Build reference dict
with open("Table A.txt", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
#     reference = defaultdict(list)
    reference = defaultdict(int)
    for row in reader:
        reference[row[0]]

# Read data and tally
with open("Table B.txt", "r") as f:
    reader2 = csv.reader(f)
#     header = next(reader2)
    for row in reader2:
        col1 = int(row[0].split()[0])
        for key in reference:
            first, last = map(int, key.split())
            if col1 >= first and col1 <= last:
#                 reference[key].append(row)
                reference[key] += 1

reference
```

The result is a dictionary that tallies the entries that fit within the given range.

```
defaultdict(int,
            {'1   524': 1,
             '1239    1790': 1,
             '2001    2321': 0,
             '3900    4567': 1,
             '677 822': 0,
             '902 1103': 0})
```

`defaultdict` gives you the option to store integers or append values to a list (see commented lines).  However, for your desired output:

```
for k, v  in reference.items():
    if v:
        print(k)
print("Total:", total)
```

Final output:

```
1   524
1239    1790
3900    4567
Total: 3
```

Comment: Thanks pylang for another useful solution.